# how can I check which class/jar is causing "Cannot inherit from final class" during WAR deployment?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, weblogic, war

I'm deploying a WAR file to a Weblogic 12.1.2 server on Windows 7 (also tried Mac OS X).

I'm getting an exception (see below). it looks like one of the classes is referring to an older/newer version of some parent class, which is coming from some duplicated jar.

how can I find which class or jar file is causing it? my WAR file has a bunch of Jars in WEB-INF/lib...

```
<Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException:
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:385)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:344)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.BeanLoaderUtils.loadBeanClassesFromJar(BeanLoaderUtils.java:54)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.BeanLoaderUtils.loadBeanClassesFromEmbeddedJar(BeanLoaderUtils.java:34)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.loadBeanClassesFromEmbeddedJar(CDIModuleExtension.java:727)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.makeInjectionArchivesForResourceType(CDIModuleExtension.java:526)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.createLibInjectionArchives(CDIModuleExtension.java:486)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.createWebModuleInjectionArchive(CDIModuleExtension.java:193)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.createInjectionArchive(CDIModuleExtension.java:179)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtension.postPrepare(CDIModuleExtension.java:85)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:297)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
```

Comment: Wow, that stack trace isn't offering any help it seems. This is a great lesson in why NOT to go back and make a class you've released final. Good luck! I guess in theory, you could write something to load each class in each jar until you hit this problem. You would have to set your classpath exactly as WebLogic has it (or presumably your build would have caught this).

Comment: May be you can try writing a standalone custom class loader class with a main() method such that it will try loading all classes in all jars from a directory one by one. Since this is a standalone program you can run it from command line and figure out which class violates the rule. Here's an example of custom class loader - http://www.codeslices.net/snippets/simple-java-custom-class-loader-implementation

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger, and set a breakpoint on the throwing of `java.lang.VerifyError`. In the ClassLoader-related part of the stack trace, at least some of the methods should have arguments that allow you to determine which class it is trying (and failing) to load.

While Weblogic is proprietary, Java itself is open source, so you might trying focusing on the lines in the stack trace starting with `at java.` But theoretically a Java debugger should even be able to debug closed-source code, to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. This error has occurred during load com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.

The solution is

1) add com.google.common.* into prefer-application-packages block in weblogic-application.xml.

2) also need check guava version. Pre 18 Guava is not compatible with JEE 6 environment. In my case I update guava from 15.0 to 18.0 version.

Comment: I had this exact same issue when using the reflections dependency and deploying in Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0. Upgrading it from 0.9.10 to 0.9.11 (which also upgraded the Guava version to 20.0) did the job.