# Failure of an application in Weblogic 12

Tags: weblogic, gwt-rpc

I have deployed a GWT application in Weblogic 10. It's working fine, but when I deploy it in Weblogic 12, the RPC call is failing showing an error "Failed while dispatching RPC call".

This is the error we are getting, but we have no final classes:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:385)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:344)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.SerializationPolicyLoader.loadFromStream(SerializationPolicyLoader.java:196)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.loadSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:93)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doGetSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:352)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.getSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:505)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:240)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:263)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
            at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3376)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3346)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2230)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
            at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:312)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:264)
```

error:

> The call failed on server, see the Server logs (500 error)

Comment: Maybe you should post some of your code

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057877/how-can-i-check-which-class-jar-is-causing-cannot-inherit-from-final-class-dur It is likely a duplicate class in your classpath. Something in your app conflicting with the base level weblogic install